# Consulta sobre Icono en exe

Tags: c#, windows-forms

**Buenas, tengo una duda con respecto a la hora de instalar mi proyecto con el **.exe**. La verdad es que cuando lo veo en el menú sin buscarlo se ve el ícono:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la barra de tareas también se ve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero, cuando ingreso la búsqueda de la aplicación no se ve el ícono:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguno sabe cómo se corrige eso? Desde ya, gracias

Comment: configuraste el ícono desde las propiedades del proyecto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¿Cómo agregaste el ícono?
¿Lo hiciste desde Visual Studio en las propiedades de tu proyecto ejecutable?
Te dejo una imagen para que lo veas mejor...

[image: Propiedades del proyecto (ejecutable)]

Según tengo entendido, esa es la forma estándar de agregar el ícono de la aplicación.
En mi caso el ícono se muestra tanto en el directorio del ejecutable, como en la barra de tareas y **en el buscador de Windows**.